# create folder in file system storage is not working in code name one

Tags: directory, codenameone

In **CodeNameOne**, I am using the following code to create a new folder but it's not working. I am testing in android simulator and mobile.

```
FileSystemStorage storage = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
storage.mkdir("tizbn");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codename One's FileSystemStorage requires absolute paths to all files, you need to either construct a path from the roots or from the app home method. Your statement assumes a current working directory which is problematic on a phone.

Comment: String[] entries = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getRoots();
            for (String name : entries) {
                System.out.println("file  name " + name);
            }
Ok the tizbn folder is created , I want to show the list of files in  the filesystemstorage But it only displays 
"file://home"
and tizbn is not displayed.

Comment: Also I have downloaded image named tizbn.jpg using following code
 Util.downloadUrlToFile(url, "tizbnImage.jpg", true);
It appears in file system storage and how to display the image in label ?

Comment: And I did not find the folder in android mobile , tablet , why?

Comment: I suggest you use getAppHomePath() as your root. Placing a file in a public SD card location requires advanced and platform specific understanding of the mobile OS. You can do that by searching for the SD card root but not all locations are writable in newer versions of Android.

Comment: I have used 2 buttons to create folder and show list of files in sdcard 
button:1
  FileSystemStorage storage = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
        storage.mkdir("tizbn");
button 2:



            String homePath = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath();
            Log.p("home path  " + homePath);

            String[] sdCardFiles = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().listFiles(homePath);

            for (String entry : sdCardFiles) {
                Log.p("file storage  " + entry);
            }
      

the tizbn folder is not shown in log, why?

Comment: Always use full path name mkdir("tiznbn") is wrong!

Comment: In the android we use "sdcard/tizbn", can we use that path or else ?
else which ?

Comment: FileSystemStorage storage = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
        String fullPath = storage.toString() + FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getFileSystemSeparator() + "tizbn";
        storage.mkdir(fullPath);

I have above code with full path but it does not create folder in sdcard why ?
how the folder can be created ?

Comment: Use list roots and traverse them. See the FileTree class to browse the files on your device hierarchy. Understand that these are different in every device and there is no single path. Just invoking the toString method is just wrong. I suggest you accept the answer and file a new question before a moderator will block this thread.